# No communication regarding wrongly-closed question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, closed-questions

I asked the question ["What word for "tomorrow can I use that is not connected with the idea of the rising sun?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186107/what-word-can-i-use-instead-of-tomorrow-that-is-not-connected-with-the-idea-of). It collected a bit of controversy (which was not my intent) and the question was put on hold. I attempted to seek advice on how to improve it and then made a fairly substantial edit that I think improves the question to a non-objectionable point.

My problem is two-fold:

- I think my question is on-topic.
- There's been no communication with me on how to make it on-topic, despite my stated willingness to change and my seeking out help.

I will discuss the second first, since the on-topic explanation is somewhat lengthy (as the rules regarding questions are somewhat lengthy.)

**No Communication**:

I am amenable to continuing to edit my question until it fits the rules of EL&U, but I would like to know how. No comments were made on the edited question, even the explicit question I asked was ignored, and those I talked to in the chat seemed satisfied. If anyone has advice on what should be changed, I would be happy to hear it.

At the time of closing, [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/186140/84957) was accepted. I accepted it mainly because the question was attracting way too much controversy and I was hoping marking an answer as "accepted" would make all the attention die down a bit. Apparently that antagonized some people (although it did achieve my goal...).

> comment via @RegDwigнt:
>
> Going by the kind of answers this has been attracting, the kind of answer that got *accepted*, and the number of flags this generates, I have to put it on hold now.

So in addition to substantially editing my question, I accepted [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/186292/84957) that had been submitted since the original accepted question, that I liked a lot more and fit my newly-reworded question better. I don't know if that was a good solution, a terrible one, even worse than the original option... I literally have no idea.

As a side note, if the problem is new and young users posting without doing any research, perhaps protecting the question would be the correct answer, not closing it?

**On-Topic?**

According to [the Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), my question fits into the topics of "Word choice and usage" and "Etymology (history of words’ development)". My question is not about these topics:

- Proofreading
- Writing advice or critique requests
- "How to improve my English?"
- Translation and non-English languages
- Naming, including naming programming variables/classes
- Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature
- Jokes that do not rely on the English language

The only topic my question might be on is "Translation and non-English languages", but the only "non-English" language I'm truly interested in is Old English. Old French and Latin are all valid language responses for my question, but that is because *English developed out of those languages*. All of the non-English languages I ask about are deeply involved in the history of English, which seems perfectly on-topic.

My question was originally somewhat open-ended, but it did have specific, measurable criteria:
 - The word must be easy to say
 - The word must make sense in a historical context; that is, it must be reasonable to assume that speakers of these languages would have developed this word given this need
 - The word must have sourced examples so that research can be verified
Thus, every answer is *not* equally valid. I ask that all answers be backed up with facts and historical references, and request all creative answers to explain "why" and "how". Thus, it seems to fit [these criteria](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

I have also edited it to make it less of a "create a word" question and more of a "find a word" question. Thus, I think my question fits the "on-topic" criteria of ELU. (I apologize if the title of this question seems a little arrogant, but according to all the rules I've been able to find, it's a true statement.)

Comment: See the help here http://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers particularly this part `As the author of the question, you have an additional option: accepting an answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.` It's you who decides what is the 'accepted answer', that is explained on this page http://english.stackexchange.com/tour `Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked.`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is on-topic and should be reopened.  You did a fine job cleaning it up.  Well done!

Comment: Thanks. :) (A simple word that does not quite accurately convey my relief at the kindness shown, but it must suffice.)

Answer (score -4):

- asking for neologisms is not a good use of the site.
- the list of bad question types (as well as recommended ones) is not comprehensive.

Comment: `My question is, what words exist in a historical context that allow the speaker to refer to time periods without necessarily connoting daytime? Or, if there are none, what words would realistically have developed given the languages present?` Did you miss the first question? Only if there were no existing words was a neologism asked for. Perhaps someone should have advised the author that the second question would be off-topic, should the first question not elicit any answers.